# how to do a navigate between photos like facebook instance

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, facebook

Q:

I want to know how to do photo navigation ,i mean photo then next and previous  to move from one to another like the one used in facebook i wanna to know how they do this flexible one.

**(photo album i means in facebook).**

(my photos comes from folders and their directory stored in the database)..

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is AJAX. Have a look at the UpdatePanel control.

Comment: okay,but i have set of photos , i wanna the first one appear only in the first then , he could navigate through next and previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use HTML and javascript. Save your list of image references in an array and select the next and previous one on onclick on the "next" "previous" buttons/links then update the `src` on the `img` tag in javascript.

```
<img src="myDefaultImage.png" id="ImageTagID" width="320" height="240" alt="this is an image" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('ImageTagID').src="newImageToShow.png";
    }
</script>
```

This ofcause snippet should get you started, calling the function `changeImage` will change the source of the image tag to something new. You'd want to get the new path from an array or something instead ofcause.

Comment: for me i did one but i don't like it so much .. it consists of an update panel contains an image and four buttons : first , last , next , previous .. but i wanna one like the facebook , it is so professional and flexible one i do my photo album with alot of complex code lines..

Comment: @just_name, I'm confused, is your problem with the design of your solution or the implementation, I was only commenting on the implementation, and suggested an easy way you could achieve it, I don't know exactly how facebook implemented it.

Comment: thanks ,and sorry for confusion ..simply ,, i make my one ,,but i want the facebook one for several reasons , i want a sample how they do it,to apply it in my application.